# iterate through a Dataframe and perform functions on row/column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, dataset, row

I have two DataFrames as below:

```
val df1 = Seq((1, 3), (2, 4), (1, 5)).toDF("col1", "col2")
example:
1  30
2  40
1  50
```

and

```
val df2 = Seq((1, 2), (3, 5)).toDF("key1", "key2")
example:
1  2
3  5
```

What I want to do is to loop through `df2`, take key2, and see if `df2.key2=df1.col1`, if so, I will add another row to `df1` to create a new DataFrame. In this example for `df2` row1 (1,2), since 2 matches row2 col1 in `df1`, I want to add another row (1,4) to `df1`.

Given the input above, the expected output is

```
      1         30    
      2         40
      1         50      
      1         40  //added this new row as result, as df2.row1.key2 matches df1.row2.col1
   //for df2(1,2), as it matches df1 (2,4)using that join condition, it brings in 4
```

I understand that we could check if `df1.col("col1")===df2.col("key2")`, but I don't know how to iterate through df2 to perform that on each row.

Comment: What about using `join` with the condition `df1.col("col2")===df2.col("key2")` and go from there?

Comment: The thing is that I need to do a lookup using df1.col("col1")===df2.col("key2") and do another join using df1.col("col1")===df2.col("key1") to do another lookup. I reckon having a more generic function would be good

Comment: Can you add expected output for the provided input?

Comment: @philantrovert Thanks. I edited the question. Let me know if I'm not explaining it very well.

Comment: where is `(1,4)` coming from?

Comment: @mtoto from df1 row2. So as df2.row1.key2 matches df1.row2.col1, it brings in col2 in df1. I edited the question too to make it a bit more clear

Comment: Your expected output looks like an inner join between `df1` and `df2` on `df1.col("col1")===df2.col("key2")` as you suggested and then a `unionAll` of joined dataframe with `df1`.